# Verifying that a communication is happening over IPSec?

Tags: networking, tcp, network-programming, vpn, ipsec

Is there a way one could test whether the communication between two hosts is happening over the **IPSec** protocol?

I have two different hosts running the OpenSource [Peer2PeerVPN](https://peervpn.net/) solution. And I have one host listening for messages via the **net-cat** tool.

```
nc -v -l -p 9999
```

And the other host connected to this via the VPN tunnel

```
nc -v 192.168.188.2 9999
```

I want to verify or check whether the communication is actually happening over the **IPSec** protocol. Also, I would like to see the values of the IPSec Protocol's **Authentication** and **Encapsulation** Headers.

I tried ***tcpdump*** but I'm guessing it only provides a capture on the layer above the Network level - Transport.

> EDIT:
>   Based on a comment below I downloaded a sample **pcap** file to view how headers look in a IPSec communication. I see that these traces have **ESP** headers of the IPSec protocol.
>
> However, when I try the same with the **VPN Tool** I'm using I don't see any packets with **ESP** header on the tcpdump. I was listening on the VPN interface *(peervpn0)* that the tool creates.
>
> To check if this was a problem with the tool, I connected to a remote server to which I usually connect using VPN and sent some data via **netcat** to my machine from inside the remote-machine *(I **ssh**'ed in)*. I listened for all packets on the VPN interface created by the **Cisco VPN Tool** *(utun0)* with filter **esp**

```
tcpdump -vvv -i utun0 esp
```

> Still, I did not see any traces.
>
> What am I missing here?
>
> Should I listen on the default interface *(my wifi interface)* via which the VPN tunnel is created to see the **ESP Headers**?
>
> Or have understood something wrong here?

Thank You
Shabir

Comment: *"I tried tcpdump but I'm guessing it only provides a capture on the layer above the Network level - Transport."* - wrong guess. tcpdump captures the network layer  too so it will capture IPSec packets.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich So will I be able to see IP Headers with some flag? Can I validate my case by seeing the addition of AH & ESP headers by running the case over the VPN tunnel and via the normal connection?

Comment: Just have a look at the various [ipsec pcap](https://www.google.com/search?q=ipsec+pcap+download) files offered for download to get a feeling for the detail you see with tcpdump or wireshark. And yes, you could create pcaps with and without VPN to see the different behavior.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will try that and get back if I am still stalled!

Comment: @SteffenUllrich -  I tried downloading a sample **pcap file** and viewing it. I saw that these files had traces of **ESP** Headers in the IPSec protocol. However, the trace did not show the TCP packets inside them.  
When I experimented in my machine ofcourse I don't see these ESP headers with the VPN tool and even on a connection to a remote server which I am surely connected over a proper VPN. I listened on the VPN interface but still saw no ESP headers. 

What am I missing here.

Comment: The VPN interface is used for the plain data. These then get encapsulated and send over the real interface (i.e. eth0 or similar). If you want to get the encapsulated packets you need to listen at the real interface not the VPN interface. And, of course you don't see the TCP headers inside ESP since everything is encrypted in the payload data of the ESP packet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With some further reading I was able to find out that **[PeerVPN](https://peervpn.net)** does not communicate over **IPSec** but using encryption and sends the data as UDP payload over the underlying interface.

I also saw that many of the VPN tools indeed do this and does encrypt the tunnel interface packets and forwards them over UDP in the underlying interface. Besides some VPN solutions have a separate option to enable **IPSec** protocol specifically.

Thank You.